# Polymer core scaffold coloring and paper button

Tags: polymer

I'm starting to use the [polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) 0.5 code to build a responsive website. I know it's not fully finished, but nevertheless I find it pretty neat and simple to get stuff done quickly.

Now, I'm using the [core-scaffold](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-scaffold) as general layout. I know how to color the sidebar, but I'm not sure where I can style the main content settings.

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <style>
            html,body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #E5E5E5;
                font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
            }

            core-toolbar {
                background: #E5E5E5;
                color: white;
            }

            paper-item.core-selected {
                color: #99182c;
                fill: #99182c;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body unresolved touch-action="auto">

        <core-scaffold>

            <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
                <core-toolbar style="background-color: #99182c; color:#fff;">Main site name</core-toolbar>
                <core-menu selected="0">
                    <paper-item icon="home" label="Home"></paper-item>
                    <paper-item icon="today" label="Activities"></paper-item>
                    <paper-item icon="account-box" label="People"></paper-item>
                    <paper-item icon="theaters" label="Pictures"></paper-item>
                    <paper-item icon="info" label="Info"></paper-item>
                    <paper-item icon="lock" label="Login"></paper-item>
                </core-menu>
            </core-header-panel>

            <div tool>Home</div>
        </core-scaffold>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the core-toolbar is styling the left sidebar, but how do I style the main page?

Another issue I'm having is that I'd like to work with the paper-elements. However, when using this `core-scaffold`, you'll notice that when the screen is small enough and the tab appears to open the left menu bar, it's a 'normal' button and not a paper one. Since this is in the `core-scaffold`, I don't directly know how to change this (if this is possible). Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and it turns out that you can style the elements (the toolbar) inside other elements (core-scaffold) using CSS with a special syntax to access the inner component (which is inside the Shadow DOM) using the `::shadow` pseudo-element.

The top rule changes the color of the title background while the second one changes the background of the content area.

```
core-scaffold::shadow core-toolbar {
  background: #E5E5E5;
  color: black;
}

core-scaffold::shadow core-header-panel {
  background: #FFF;
  color: black;
}
```

Source: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/#toc-style-cat-hat

**Update**: This didn't work properly with Firefox because of shims. What did it was adding styles with the `shim-shadowdom` directive that gets interpreted only when on [a non webcomponent/shadowdom native platform](http://robdodson.me/blog/2014/04/10/shadow-dom-css-cheat-sheet/#shadow):

```
<style shim-shadowdom>
  core-scaffold core-toolbar {
    background: #EEE;
    color: black;
  }

  core-scaffold #main core-header-panel {
    background: #FFF;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
```

Note that to change the background of the content area I also had to select `#main` so porting `::shadow` rules might need a bit of inspecting...

Finally when you need to properly deal with Firefox and other browsers from within a webcomponent/polymer element you can [use the `polyfill-rule` or `polyfill-unscoped-rule`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#at-polyfill-rule).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to change the style from the navy blue by digging into the  tag in the  /bower_components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html and changing the background-color; however this changes all the defaults.

Comment: also its a div the main title so add a class and style like thaT

Comment: You will lose all your modifications on a `bower update`.