# Styling polymer core-scaffold

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom

By default the background-color of side nav in `core-scaffold` is white and the background-color of content is close to grey. I want to reverse these styles, so that the background-color of side nav is grey and the content is white.
I added following rules and they do what I want on Chrome:

```
core-scaffold::shadow core-drawer-panel>div[vertical] {
    background-color: grey;
}

core-scaffold::shadow core-drawer-panel core-header-panel {
    background-color: white;
}
```

But it doesn't work on Firefox. I've read that I need to use `polyfill-next-selector` but I can't understand how it works. I tried to prepend `polyfill-next-selector {content: '::shadow'}` to my styles but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with selector #1 here is that there's another element between `core-drawer-panel` and the div. It's hidden in `core-drawer-panel`'s shadow DOM:

```
core-scaffold
  (shadow root)
     core-drawer-panel
       (shadow root)
         core-selector
       div[drawer]
```

So with native shadow DOM `core-drawer-panel > div` selects it. But a non-shadow DOM browser sees this as:

```
core-scaffold
  core-drawer-panel
    core-selector
      div[drawer]
```

The div is no longer a direct child of the `core-drawer-panel`, so your selector doesn't work.

I think the issue with the second selector may involve selector specificity. (It doesn't look to me like your rule should work in Chrome, either, but it does.)

How to work around this? Use the `drawer` and `main` attributes instead:

```
core-scaffold::shadow [drawer] {
    background-color: grey;
}

core-scaffold::shadow [main] {
    background-color: white;
}
```

You don't need `polyfill-next-selector` for these rules. In fact, you rarely need it at all these days. You only need it for rules that:

- include `:content` in the selector, AND
- DON'T work if  you simply remove the `:content`

For more information on `polyfill-next-selector`, see: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#at-polyfill

Comment: Thanks, @DocDude. It's much cleaner to use `[drawer]` and `[main]`, but somehow it doesn't work on Firefox neither. Did you test it? Maybe something is wrong with my markup?

Comment: tried `polyfill-rule` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24617427/632027) - but it didn't help :(

Comment: Yes, this works for me. If you're applying the styles outside of a polymer element, be sure to include the `shim-shadowdom` attribute on the `<style>` tag. See: http://jsbin.com/giviho/6/edit

Comment: To clarify: the jsbin above works in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Is `shim-shadowdom` attribute supposed to work with `<link>` as well?

Comment: Yes, it should. See: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#sdcss

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
<style shim-shadowdom>
   core-scaffold::shadow core-drawer-panel>div[vertical] {
       background-color: grey;
   }

   core-scaffold::shadow core-drawer-panel core-header-panel {
       background-color: white;
   }
</style>
```

[http://robdodson.me/shadow-dom-css-cheat-sheet/](http://robdodson.me/shadow-dom-css-cheat-sheet/#shadow)

Answer (score 0):

Just inspected the markup with Firefox and found a solution:

On Chrome:

```
core-scaffold::shadow [drawer] {
    background-color: rgba(243, 241, 255, 1);
}

core-scaffold::shadow [main] {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

On Firefox:

```
core-scaffold [drawer] {
    background-color: rgba(243, 241, 255, 1);
}

core-scaffold [main] {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```